# How do I generate a 403 error when someone tries to access a particular page

Tags: http

I may be barking up completely the wrong tree here but what I would like to do is protect my .js pages by having them return a 403 Forbidden http error status page if someone tries to access them directly via http. I use them to support my index.html page but would like for them to remain hidden.

The helpdesk guys at my ISP basically say they don't know if it's possible but it may be something you could do with a web.config file (which is not something I have used before).

Any help at all would be gratefully received - I am a bit out of my comfort zone with this one

Comment: We need to know which kind of platform it is. JSP? PHP?

Comment: What server do you use? (apache, lighttpd, etc)?

Comment: You can certainly return a 403 by checking against the Referer (sic) header, but it may not make much difference. This will guard against someone else using your JS on their page or accessing it directly, but you can never stop someone from downloading your JS all together. The Referer header can also be spoofed.

Comment: _“I use them to support my index.html page”_ – define “support”, please.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys :) Overall it seems like it would be a waste of time to try and do this. I was just experimenting with idea - thought it would be much more straightforward (and effective) than it appears to be. Just so you know CBroe I meant that the .js pages are used as external files that are linked to in the <script> tag in the header of my html files :)

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to […] protect my .js pages by having them return a 403 Forbidden http error status page if someone tries to access them directly via http.

Please note that if you include some resource, for example a script via the `<script>`-tag in HTML or an image via the `<img>`-tag, the browser does nothing else than simply run another HTTP request to get that resource. The whole communication already happens over HTTP.

While a browser *may* include additional details in its HTTP request when requesting additional resources, like the Referer-header, it definitely is not required to do so. So if you look out for the Referer-header, be advised that you may lock out other valid clients which do not send the Referer-header in their requests.

Also note that this will not give you any protection whatsoever. One can simply construct HTTP headers when requesting things, so “faking” requests your server would allow (because it thinks they are correct) is not a problem at all. And even without that; every resource you tell the client to use to make your website work *will be downloaded* by the client. And after that, the client can do whatever he wants with it. It can cache them on the hard disk, or allow the user to quickly look at it without having to run another request.

So if you want to do this for protecting your code, then just forget about it, and make it easier for everyone by just not adding a non-optimal protection. Code you put on the web can be made difficult to read, but if you want the user to see the end result, then you also give out your code in the same step.

Answer (score 1):

In php you can do this with:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
```